# How can I connect a Kyocera ECOSYS P5021cdw printer to my WiFi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, printer, network-printer

The Kyocera ECOSYS P5021cdw laser printer supports WiFi but doesn't allow you to enter the SSID and password on its own front panel.

How can I connect it to my Wifi network, so I can print from it?

I only have a Mac available with no CD drive, no PC, so I can't use the software DVD that came with the printer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pain to do. I discovered a few ways:

1. Find the WPS option in the printer front-panel menu, and press the WPS button on your router to pair them. This did not work for me (don't know why not).
2. Log in to your router's web interface and tell it to find a WPS device. Choose the WPS option in the router front-panel menu, to pair them. This worked for me.
3. Connect to the printer by USB, access the printer's web interface (on MacOS 10.13 that's: print queue -> options & supplies -> Show printer web page). This would have worked for me if I'd known the default username and password to log in to the printer's web interface (which will allow you to set up this stuff). Turns out it is username **Admin**, password **Admin**. *NB It is not the same username/password as the administrator login for the printer front-panel menu.*
4. Connect to it by wifi-direct. Use the printer's web interface as in (3) above.

Answer (score 1):

I'd the same problem with the same printer and a MacBook Pro without CD-Drive. I want to add a solution that worked in my case.

- Make sure via the front panel, that DHCP is activated
- Connect the printer via LAN cable to your local network (in my case I've got a switch)
- Scan your network (i.e. with LanScan for Mac) and find the entry with your printers ID and copy the IP
- Open Browser and paste the IP
- Login with username "Admin", password "Admin"
- Find the Network Configuration section
- Deactivate WiFi-direct (if activated) and put in the data for your WLAN

Comment: IMPORTANT: Please note that the WIFI module of this printer is obviously only capable of 2,4 GHz. IT DOES NOT WORK WITH 5GHz.